# Removing blank spaces from ends of array in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, trim

I have several arrays of lines of output in a program that use '#' and ' '. The arrays could be any combination of these two elements, i.e.

```
[..., #, #, #, #, ' ', ' ', ...]
[..., #, #, ' ', ' ', #, #, ...]
[..., ' ', ' ', #, #, ' ', ' ', ...] etc.
```

Is there a way of trimming the start and end of the array to remove all ' ' until a # is found and leave all ' ' between the # alone?

Answer (score 0):

use join and rindex / index to find the last / first occurrence of #

```
res = ''.join(array).rindex('#')
```

then use del to delete everything before and after

```
del array[res:]
```